# iPhone SDK: Transparent tableviewcell isn't transparent?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, transparency

I have a UITableViewController that has a background image. I am setting the image for the tableview like this:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:
@"background1.jpg"]]]];
```

The problem is, each of my custom tableview cells get the same background image--it's repeated in each cell. As a test, I tried making everything in my cell transparent with an alpha of 0.0, but even then although I can't see any of the labels in each cell, I still see the background image repeated in each cell:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.alpha = 0.0;
cell.alpha = 0.0;
```

Any suggestions on how to get my table's background image to stop repeating in each cell would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `opaque` property to `NO`? It's defined in `NSView`.

```
[cell setOpaque:NO];
```

It's defined in the Apple API as follows:

> YES if it is opaque; otherwise, NO. If
>   opaque, the drawing operation assumes
>   that the view fills its bounds and can
>   draw more efficiently. The results are
>   unpredictable if opaque and the view
>   doesn’t fill its bounds. Set this
>   property to NO if the view is fully or
>   partially transparent. The default
>   value is YES.